# Was a flamethrower used to incinerate Skripal's cat after its death?

Tags: united-kingdom

In March 2018, British spy [Sergei Skripal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_of_Sergei_and_Yulia_Skripal) is believed to have been poisoned in his home with a nerve agent. Wikipedia explains his three pets died:

> On 5 April 2018, British authorities said that inside Sergey Skripal's house, which had been sealed by the police, two guinea pigs were found dead by vets, when they were allowed in, along with a cat in a distressed state. The guinea pigs were reported to have died of thirst; the cat was taken for testing to the Porton Down chemical weapons facility, where all three bodies were incinerated.

Russia 24, a Russian state-controlled TV channel, broadcast [a news report](https://ura.news/news/1052330177) that discusses how the cat was incinerated (after being euthanized):

> what's important, they did not use a specialized crematorium, but a flamethrower.

Was a flamethrower used to incinerate Skripal's cat?

Comment: I wonder if it is a case of a [driptorch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driptorch) or similar being confused with a [military flamethrower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flamethrower#Military_flamethrowers).

Comment: What evidence did Russia 24 provide for this claim?  If the answer is none then the claim can be dismissed as claims made without evidence can be dismissed without evidence.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question that can be answered, especially if the news report doesn't say *why* they think a flamethrower was used. Best I can find is that the cat [was possibly euthanized](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2018/apr/06/sergei-skripal-cat-guinea-pigs-die-police-sealed-house-salisbury-spy) at a lab [which would definitely have a crematorium available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porton_Down#Use_of_animals).

Comment: The source of the story that the cat was euthanized and incinerated is the Sun: https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/5983643/skripals-beloved-cat-nash-van-drake-had-to-be-secretly-put-down-following-the-poison-attack/ The Sun makes no mention of a flamethrower. The Russia 24 piece is over-the-top with comparisons to the burning of witches and tongue-in-cheek speculation as to the danger which the second cat (location unknown) may pose to "all of Europe". They cite no source for the bit about the flamethrower and I can find none.